# How can I tell if a stalker is going to kill me?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Every once in a while, a templar stalker will come and attempt to take my life (and will always be unsuccessful ;).

Are there any conditions for when they do attack me?  Is it completely random?  Is there any way for me to see them nearby so I can attack first?

The last time I was attacked, I noticed that I'm still completely **secret** from the templars.  I don't remember how aware they were of me the other times.

Comment: I thought they only stabbed you, but not actually kill you. The easy way to get pay back is to try and keep one of your Assassin's ready that if something happens you can send him to kill him. Saves you some running!

Comment: What i do is get like a splinter bomb and throw it into a crowd of people they will all die obviously make sure there is a group of guards nearby or maybe a rooftop guard once the people are dead the guard will come and inspect it dont be right next to the dead bodys or they will suspect u once he has inspected hopefully he will start attacking a person who will try to run away and u guessed it is a stalker tht works each time i try it good luck :) also note that if u havnt read the assassins creed wiki they come in groups some times after getting attacked by one look around in eagle vision...

Comment: Comment continues: ...they will be red also if the leader of the group of stalkers runs away of is killed the others will flee as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been attacked by stalkers in crowds, on rooftops, and in deserted corners of the city. I have been attacked by stalkers with an empty Templar awareness meter, and a full one. I have gone hours and hours without seeing one, and then gotten several almost back to back to back.

As far as I can tell, it's either totally random, or it's planned to look like it's totally random.

Comment: To solve the assassination attempts, counter kill the stalkers. I even believe that you use their on weapon to kill them.

Answer (score 4):

You mostly just have to pay attention - your Templar Awareness doesn't seem to have anything to do with it.  There's usually dramatic music right before they hit you, though, so if you hear music while you're just wandering around that's your hint to take notice.

If you unlock the Mercenary faction ability, when you have mercenaries with you they will intercept any stalkers that might show up.

EDIT: I'm really not sure about this, but I have the subjective sense that they do seem to show up more often when you're in thick crowds.  I don't recall seeing one show up when I was on an empty street...I'm really not sure about this, though.  I've certainly been attacked when I'm not blending and not anywhere near a clump of NPCs.  The only other thing I can really say is that I've never seen them attack when I'm on a rooftop, but then of course you're risking the attention of rooftop sentries anyway.

Comment: I had a feeling it happened more often when I was sneaking around and trying to follow some NPC when on a quest, but obviously those 3 occasions are hardly evidence

Comment: It's not quite the answer I was looking for.  I know when they actually are moving in for the attack and can stop them, that's the easy part.  But I'm looking for what in the game "makes" them attack.  Much like how having a fully red templar awareness makes them eventually attack your dens.  Is this a random event?  Or are there controllable factors that makes them want to attack?  I'd rather proactively stop them rather than wait for them to attack me.

Comment: It's not quite the answer I like to give, but having sunk 20+ hours into this game at this point I can see absolutely no pattern whatsoever.  They've attacked me with full awareness, empty awareness, when I'm running around, when I'm standing still, I dunno.  I made a slight edit but this is really just conjecture on my part.

Comment: It always seems to happen to me after I've killed a bunch of (non-Templar) guards for fun (which I do sometimes). I'm looting their bodies and everyone around me is horrified, and then somebody tries to off me.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller - Maybe it is just more likely to happen in crowds, and so the fact that you're loitering in a spot with a lot of people does it?  I pretty much never kill guards and I still get stalkers.

Comment: @Shinrai I bet you're right. (I think I spend more time randomly fighting with guards than I do actually participating in memories.)

Comment: The other day I was looting a chest in an empty corner by the water with hardly anyone around and I had an assassination attempt. I think it really is just random.

Answer (score 3):

When there is one close, you'll hear whispers all around.

Just go to multiplayer, it's the same sound when a pursuer is near.

And the timing is random. You can have none for 3 hours then 2 in 10 minutes.

EDIT: Just a theory like that, I think they might appear more often if you stand for a long  time in the same part of the city. I remember when I was just waiting close to a bank for my income to cash in (so a few hours in the same part of the city, just waiting) and by the end, it was one each 10 to 15 minutes. Just a theory, that should be tested.

Answer (score 2):

I always go to the Grand Bazaar. Go to the Tailor shop that is just near one of the exits and just wait for less than 5 minutes. I just tested it and I got one in 2 minutes, but I am suggesting 5 minutes just in case it may be longer for some other players. I hope this info will help.

I also did this especially because I had 1 very tiny bit of red on my Templar Awareness meter and i wanted to get rid of it. Now I have. Of course The Grand Bazaar is a huge place, lots of people, some guards and a lot of shops, Almost every time I have gone inside the Bazaar I have been attacked by these guys, but what annoys me, is even though i kill them every time before getting stabbed, my stats show no kills on stalkers. That's weird.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Alison! The second paragraph of your answer sounds like it could make a good question ("why do my stats show zero kills on the stalkers?"). You can post it using the Ask Question button in the top right of the page and hopefully someone will have the answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just like in the online mode you hear whispering when they are near. The closer you are, the louder the whisper.

They also show up as a dagger on the mini map.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, when you think one is near (by hearing distinct whispers), you should scan the area with eagle vision and you might spot a red civilian. After you exit eagle vision it should be marked on your map as the dagger.

If you walk near them they will attack. I've also noticed a civilian acting unusual by either holding something behind his back or constantly adjusting his clothing. It's pretty obvious once you notice this.

I also seem to come in contact with stalkers right after or during a mission.

Answer (score 1):

You'll see an icon of a white knife on your minimap when a Stalker is near you.

Comment: Really? I've never seen this. But I'm never looking for it...

Comment: @Abby: I can confirm that you can see it _after_ they've attacked you, but can't say for sure if they appear approaching you before it.

Comment: @Jeff I wouldn't know. They never escape my grasp alive.

Answer (score -2):

yes dramatic music definitly comes when a stalker comes so whenever that happens i always stop moving because i like putting the throwing knife in his neck (though it doesn't affect my throwing knife ammount) but sometimes when your still moving at just the right moment you can see the stalker about to run into you and automatically you push him the distance you would throw him and then switch to hidden blade and assassinate him. stalkers usually come (for me) mostly when I'm looting dead ottoman guards (on the minimap yellowish blips not red unless your in a restricted area cause the red ones are the byzantines the ones who want to kill you when they see you but in restricted areas those red blips are ottomans who want to kill you when they see you or anybody really cause it's a restricted area!) and everybody knows loot stalkers! and i've noticed stalkers come when your low on money (such as 234 a) and those guys that have a blip that looks like an eye that lowers your templar awareness (when you kill him) by 50% come when the awareness bar is almost full or aware rather than secret

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything.  You just repeat the same theory that everyone else did.